# PHP run loop continuously until get = stop

Tags: php, shell

I'm trying to turn a Raspberry pi relay on/off like a strobe, but I can't seem to stop the while loop, the page loads, and the relay starts to pulse, but I can't stop it. The only way is to stop the whole web service.

Here is my code:

```html
 <?php
if($_GET['type'] == 'switch') {
 $output = shell_exec('gpio mode '.$_GET['pin'].' out');
 $output = shell_exec('gpio write '.$_GET['pin'].' '.$_GET['status']);
}

if($_GET['type'] == 'blink') {
while(1) {
   $output = shell_exec('gpio write 1 0'); 
   sleep(0.1);
   $output = shell_exec('gpio write 1 1'); 
   break;
 
 


   }
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, you need to give it a condition to stop. What do you want it to be? After X blinks? After X seconds? After...?

Comment: I need it to stop when I send stop=stop to that php page. I'm posting to that url via a mobile app, I need the motor to pulse continiously until Said Stop var is sent to the page

Answer (score 0):

Your break; statement doesn't stop the while loop, it only breaks from the loop and then checks the while condition again.

I recommend giving it a condition rather than a 1.

```
while (led == 'on')
{
    //Your code

    if (when you want it to stop)
    {
         led = 'off';
    }

}
```

Also, just a personal recommendation. Your page will never stop because the code will always be running. What you can do is run a file that controls the led. This way, your page can stop running and the led, via a program on the pi rather than the website, can run instead. Thus, your code will detect for "start" or "stop" variable and if it is set, then it will run the "start_led" program.

If you do this, make sure to kill the process that is controlling the led before starting another one. In your "start_led" program, you can just ps -aux | grep "start_led" and then use the kill command to stop that program from running.